# How to add Identity column into existing table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I add an identity column into a MySQL table. The table is imported from a csv and I can't edit the create table function manually. I tried to create the identity column using the following code :

```
ALTER TABLE apple_predictor_predictions 
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1);
```

Comment: MYSQL does not supprt the IDENTITY

Comment: Do you mean AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I tried to work with auto increment as well. Could you please share sample code to do this?

Comment: You can do something like this: 
alter table test add column id integer auto_increment primary key;